# Delay in a WinForms app without using "await Task.Delay(x)"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I'm creating a poker app and i want to make some sort of simulation of the throwing of the cards effect and to do that I currently use `await Task.Delay(x);` However this requires async Task and if i switch this method where i do the task.delay(x) to async i will have to change at least 5-6 more into async as well. I suppose this is fine for someone that understand the exact way the asynchronus works. Currently im getting a lot of logic errors simply because i obviously don't know how async and await operators work.. In other words I'm newbie, and is there any alternative to this exact line `await Task.Delay(x);` I wont use anything else that is connected to async just this line.

Here's the code :

```
private async Task Shuffle()
{
    Bitmap refreshBackImage = new Bitmap(getBack);
    bCall.Enabled = false;
    bRaise.Enabled = false;
    bFold.Enabled = false;
    bCheck.Enabled = false;
    MaximizeBox = false;
    MinimizeBox = false;
    bool check = false;
    horizontal = tbChips.Left - _settings.Width * 2 - 15;
    vertical = pbTimer.Top - _settings.Height - (_settings.Height) / 7;
    RNGCrypto random = new RNGCrypto();
    for (i = ImgLocation.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j = random.Next(i);
        string k = ImgLocation[j];
        ImgLocation[j] = ImgLocation[i - 1];
        ImgLocation[i - 1] = k;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        Deck[i] = Image.FromFile(ImgLocation[i]);
        string[] charsToRemove = { getCards, ".png", "\\" };
        foreach (string c in charsToRemove)
        {
            ImgLocation[i] = ImgLocation[i].Replace(c, string.Empty);
        }
        Reserve[i] = int.Parse(ImgLocation[i]) - 1;
        Holder[i] = new PictureBox
        {
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            Height = _settings.Height,
            Width = _settings.Width
        };
        Controls.Add(Holder[i]);
        Holder[i].Name = "pb" + i;
        await Task.Delay(150);

        #region Throwing Cards
        SetPlayers(Player, i, ref check, 560, 470, refreshBackImage);
        SetPlayers(Bot1, i, ref check, 15, 420, refreshBackImage);
        SetPlayers(Bot2, i, ref check, 75, 65, refreshBackImage);
        SetPlayers(Bot3, i, ref check, 590, 25, refreshBackImage);
        SetPlayers(Bot4, i, ref check, 1115, 65, refreshBackImage);
        SetPlayers(Bot5, i, ref check, 1160, 420, refreshBackImage);
        if (i >= 12)
        {
            Holder[12].Tag = Reserve[12];
            if (i > 12) Holder[13].Tag = Reserve[13];
            if (i > 13) Holder[14].Tag = Reserve[14];
            if (i > 14) Holder[15].Tag = Reserve[15];
            if (i > 15)
            {
                Holder[16].Tag = Reserve[16];

            }
            if (!check)
            {
                horizontal = 410;
                vertical = 265;
            }
            check = true;
            if (Holder[i] != null)
            {
                Holder[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                Holder[i].Image = refreshBackImage;
                //Holder[i].Image = Deck[i];
                Holder[i].Location = new Point(horizontal, vertical);
                horizontal += 110;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        Bot1 = (Bot)FoldedPlayer(Bot1);
        Bot2 = (Bot)FoldedPlayer(Bot2);
        Bot3 = (Bot)FoldedPlayer(Bot3);
        Bot4 = (Bot)FoldedPlayer(Bot4);
        Bot5 = (Bot)FoldedPlayer(Bot5);
        if (i == 16)
        {
            if (!restart)
            {
                MaximizeBox = true;
                MinimizeBox = true;
            }
            Turns();
        }
    }
    Ending();
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Doesn't it make much more sense to you to *learn* about async instead of asking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For things like animations, you might want the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` component, which raises a periodic event.

You can configure the interval as well as temporarily disabling it entirely.

Note that after the delay, you'll be back to the top of the handler function... it doesn't automatically keep track of where you are in your sequence the way the `await` keyword automatically resumes at the next line.  So you'll need some counter or such to let you know what step of the animation is coming next.

Comment: @usr: Yes and no.  The changes to the timed code will be invasive, but the game logic can just `TimerCardThrown.Enabled = true;` and go on.

Comment: Exactly this resuming is causing quite some troubles and i'm in the middle of my project.Yes i will take a look at async but once i'm done ..

Comment: @usr: Really the problem is a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.  The "Shuffle" method is currently responsible for at least three things: randomizing order of cards, associating them to players, and UI animation, with some file access mixed in for no good reason.  If these were separated, writing the animation using either `await` or a Timer would be trivial.

Comment: Can you give me a tip on how should i separate the method or which parts  should be refactored in new methods

Comment: @denis: Each of the three things I mentioned should be a separate function.  Please note that you don't have to follow the real world exactly -- even though in the real world a card is removed from the deck, then moves across the table, then is added to the player's hand, in a computer game it's perfectly reasonable to calculate all the cards that will be in each hand in about 2 nanoseconds, then start the animation that visually depicts the dealing process over a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to do the async, because it wont come back until it's complete. Meaning if you want something timed. Async will have some trouble providing this for you. Because you'll either have to wait for the response which may be an issue. Especially if its a game. Watch how the async functions in debug and you'll understand. An event trigger, or just a timed event will work much better because you'll have the control of when it triggers or how a long you wait for the event. This will get rid of your delay all together or it should.

In your case, a simple trigger event at the time, will display the throwing of cards, and once finished will continue on with your function. That's simple terms, you may have to do a few things like waiting until that trigger is finished. Either way there is a ton of information regarding events. Have a look before you go for async. Since it's forms you can do it however you please, if it for windows phone or other types of systems some require async only.

this should help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z(v=vs.90).aspx